# Android custom adapters

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I'm using Android's custom adapters to create a list view for my application. I'm looking to  show whether or  not someone's in first, second or third place and also show unique badges for each person in the list. The code below works for ranking but it shows the same badges for each person. I can't quite seem to figure out why. If a person doesn't earn a badge, he or she should not see anything (when I set the array to null) each person's badges are set to null. I've been debugging this for a while and can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I imagine it's something simple. Thanks!

```
   public class LeaderArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserStatus> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = "LeaderArrayAdapter";
        private final Context context;
        // UserStatus class: contains a text value - user name, an 
        // integer value for the place (1st,2nd,3rd..) and an integer array for user 
        // badges 
        private final UserStatus[] values; 

        // array of icons to represent a ribbon for each place (1st,2nd..)  
        private static int[] placeIcons ={ R.drawable.first_ribbon1,
           R.drawable.ribbon_2, R.drawable.ribbon_3, R.drawable.ribbon_4,                
           R.drawable.ribbon_5, R.drawable.ribbon_6, R.drawable.ribbon_7,   
           R.drawable.ribbon_8, R.drawable.ribbon_9, R.drawable.ribbon_10, 
           R.drawable.ribbon_11, R.drawable.ribbon_12, R.drawable.ribbon_13, 
           R.drawable.ribbon_14, R.drawable.ribbon_15}; 

        // This variable array contains the layout each badge should be placed - up to 9 
        // badges
        private static int[] badgeIconLayout = {R.id.action1, R.id.action2,  
           R.id.action3, R.id.action4, R.id.action5, R.id.action6, R.id.action7, 
           R.id.action8, R.id.action9}; 

        // this array contains the specific R values that represent each badge in the 
           drawables folder
        private static int[] badgeIcons = {R.drawable.aa, R.drawable.ab, R.drawable.ac, 
           R.drawable.ad, R.drawable.ae,R.drawable.af, R.drawable.ag, R.drawable.ah, 
           R.drawable.ai, R.drawable.aj, R.drawable.ak, R.drawable.al, R.drawable.am, 
           R.drawable.an};  

        public LeaderArrayAdapter(Context context, UserStatus[] values) {
            super(context, R.layout.leaderboard_rowlayout, values);
            this.context = context;
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // Each row will contain a place icon, user name, user value, and user 
            // badges. These values come from the UserStatus variable values
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leaderboard_rowlayout, null, true);
            TextView userName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.userName1);
            ImageView placeView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.place);
            userName.setText(values[position].name); 
            placeView.setImageResource(placeIcons[position]); 

            // If there are badges associated with this UserStatus, loop through each 
            // badge position (only show 9) and place the associated icon

            // The number of badges, identifies the badge location on the layout 
            // (badgeIconLayout - ie, position 1, 2, or 3)
            // We only want to set badge icons for those users with badges 
            if(values[position].badges != null){
                for(int i=0; i<values[position].badges.length; i++){
                    if(i<9){
                        // Select the icon layout position and set the image resource 
                        // accordingly
                        ImageView badgeView = 
                                    (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(badgeIconLayout[i]);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "images to set = " + values[position].badges[i]);
                    badgeView.setImageResource(badgeIcons[values[position].badges[i]]);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                /*ImageView badgeView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(badgeIconLayout[0]);
                actionView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
                return rowView;*/
            }
            return rowView;
        }
    }
```

The key part of the ListActivity is below:

```
            // inputarray represents all of the users returned from our database
            // the php file returns all users in order (according to 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. 
            // place
            while(i<inputarray.length()){
                UserStatus user = new UserStatus();
                user.name = inputarray.getJSONArray(1).getString(i);
                user.score=inputarray.getJSONArray(0).getString(i);

                // this method loops through the server array to store badges
                int [] myArray = getUserBadges(user.name);
                user.badges = myArray;
                user.iconPlace = i;
                values[i]=user;
                i++;

            }

            // Once we've stored all information about the users, we call setListAdapter
            // I've checked that this works as expected
            setListAdapter(new LeaderArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),values));
```

Comment: The code's a little difficult to follow. Comments would be helpful. Any reason you're setting the badge view 9 times? It will always be set to the last value anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I added comments (and code for the ListView). 9 is the maximum number of badges that I will show. IE, I show up to 9 different badges. It actually sets to the first badge value.

Comment: Hmm, is there a way for me to close this question? I've identified the problem and it's completely different from what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't look through your code, and would probably like to see the code for your custom adapter.

I would suggest in your custom adapter, that you determine the value of the award for that particular line item, and set the badge image specifically at that time.

so in your adapter (pseude-code):

```
if (user.getAward() == myRedValue) {
    awardImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_award);
} else if (user.getAward() == myBlueValue) {
    awardImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_award);
} etc...
```

Comment: Hmm, I sent the code for the custom adapter. I added code for the ListView.