# ListView is not shows the correct images that are in the drawable according to their name in sqlite

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

I have an android application that use sqlite as **DB** and fetch data from **DB** then display these data in the `ListView`.

The problem is that it is not display the correct images according to their names in the sqlite database so how to fix this error?

can anyone help me?

## CustomAdapterMatchSchedule.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ItemDetails itemdetail = itemdetailsList.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_match_schedule,
                null);
    }
    // Stad_name
    TextView txtStadName = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textLocation);
    txtStadName.setText(itemdetail.getStad_name());
    // team1
    TextView txtTeam1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName1);
    txtTeam1.setText(itemdetail.getTeam1());
    // team2
    TextView txtTeam2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName2);
    txtTeam2.setText(itemdetail.getTeam2());

    // flag1
    int imageid = context.getResources().getIdentifier("brazil_flag",
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imagenow.setImageResource(imageid);

    // flag2
    int imageid2 = context.getResources().getIdentifier("croatian_flag",
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    ImageView imagenow2 = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imagenow.setImageResource(imageid2);

    // match_date
    TextView txtmatch_date = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
    txtmatch_date.setText(itemdetail.getDate_match());

    // group
    TextView txtGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);
    txtGroup.setText(itemdetail.getGroup());

    return convertView;
}
```

## MatchScheduleList.java

```
package com.devleb.expandablelistdemo3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MatchScheduleList extends Activity {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "world_cup.db";
    // *****Tables name**************************//
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "match_list";

    // *****Tbale name******************************//

    public static final String PLACE_ID = "_id";
    public static final String STAD_NAME = "stad_name";
    public static final String TEAM1 = "team1";
    public static final String TEAM2 = "team2";
    public static final String STAGE = "stage";
    public static final String MATCH_DATE = "match_date";
    public static final String GROUP = "group_team";
    public static final String FLAG1 = "flags1";
    public static final String FLAG2 = "flags2";

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { PLACE_ID, STAD_NAME,
            TEAM1, TEAM2, STAGE, MATCH_DATE, FLAG1, FLAG2, GROUP };
    // *****Tbale name******************************//

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView myList;
    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> list = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

    ItemDetails listdetail;

    private ExternalDbOpenHelper extDB;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_schedule_list);

        ExternalDbOpenHelper extDB = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = extDB.openDataBase();


        populateLitsFromDB();
    }

    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;

        Cursor c = database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, where, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {

            c.moveToFirst();

            listdetail = new ItemDetails();
            listdetail
                    .setDate_match(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date")));

            listdetail.setGroup(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("group_team")));

            listdetail.setTeam1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team1")));

            listdetail.setTeam2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("team2")));

            listdetail.setStad_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("stad_name")));
            listdetail
                    .setDate_match(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("match_date")));

            listdetail.setFlag1(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("flags1")));

            listdetail.setFlag2(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("flags2")));

            list.add(listdetail);

        }

        return c;

    }

    private void populateLitsFromDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Cursor cursor = getAllRows();

        // allo0w activity to manage life cicle of the cursor

        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        CustomAdapterMatchSchedule customAdapter = new CustomAdapterMatchSchedule(
                this, list);

        Log.d("in the getAllRows", customAdapter.toString());

        // set the adapter for te listView
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        myList.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.match_schedule_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not passing values coming from DB to imageView. But two hard coded values **brazil_flag** and **croatian_flag** have been passed instead.

Comment: Images for hard coded values are also not displayed ?

Comment: @ Dig  what you mean by your comment where i am doing wrong ?? and how to get these data (images) from my sqlite database according to their names in my code ???

Comment: what i meant is do you get image by writing following code
 `int imageid = context.getResources().getIdentifier("brazil_flag",
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imagenow.setImageResource(imageid);`

Comment: YES I GET the image but the problem is that i have over 50 images in the drawable folder and their names exist in the sqlite database so how to make all these images appear and not just the **(brazil_flag)** in all the list ??

Comment: Instead of hard-coded text - `brazil_flag`, write the name fetched from db. Like, `int imageid = context.getResources().getIdentifier(itemdetail.getFlag1(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());`

Comment: thank you  Dig it work make your comment an answer to be able to mark it  as correct

Comment: @user3573907 Welcome. I think i gave correct answer for your previous 2 questions also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hard-coded text - `brazil_flag`, write the name fetched from db. Like,

```
int imageid = context.getResources().getIdentifier(itemdetail.getFlag1(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
ImageView imagenow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imagenow.setImageResource(imageid);
```